# Counting certain elements in lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following data set:

```
n1 = 1000;
data1 = {#, {RandomInteger[3, 20]}} & /@ Range[n1];

Dimensions@data1
{1000, 2}
```

I want to count how often `data1[[All, 2]] == 1`.

My solution:

```
result1 = Table[
   Count[Flatten@(data1[[i, 2]]), u_ /; u == 1],
   {i, 1, n1}
   ];

Dimensions@result1
{1000}
```

Now I have 50 appended lists of `data1` (= `data2`).

```
n3 = 50;

data2 = Array[0 &, n3];

Do[
  data2[[i]] = {#, {RandomInteger[3, 20]}} & /@ Range[n1];
  , {i, 1, n3}
  ];

Dimensions@data2
{50, 1000, 2}
```

I want to count how often `data2[[j, i, 2]] == 1`, where `{i, 1, n1}` and `{j, 1, n3}`.

My solution for this more complicated list:

```
result2 = Array[0 &, n3];

Do[
  result2[[j]] =
    Table[
     Count[Flatten@(data2[[j, i, 2]]), u_ /; u == 1],
     {i, 1, n1}
     ];
  , {j, 1, n3}
  ];

Dimensions@result2
{50, 1000}
```

**How can I *replace the Do loops* in both cases and improve the performance?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
r1 = Total[1 - Unitize[data1[[All, 2, 1]] - 1], {2}] 

Short @ %
```

> {5,5,4,6,5,8,5,6,5,4,8,6,3,3,2,7,2,9,5,6,4,5,3,8,7,6,8,3,7,5,9,4,7,6,5,4,5,5,<<925>>,7,5,6,6,3,5,4,6,6,9,7,9,5,6,4,3,8,4,4,6,6,9,6,6,3,8,3,4,1,8,4,4,4,5,7,8,5}

```
r2 = Join @@@ Total[1 - Unitize[data2[[All, All, 2]] - 1], {4}];
r2 // Dimensions
```

> {50, 1000}

**Timings:** Timing comparison with OP's `Do` loop and MarcoB's `Map[Count,...]` for `data2`:

```
n1 = 1000;
n3 = 50;
data2 = Array[0 &, n3];
SeedRandom[1]
Do[data2[[i]] = {#, {RandomInteger[3, 20]}} & /@ Range[n1];, {i, 1, n3}];

result2a = Join @@@ Total[1 - Unitize[data2[[All, All, 2]] - 1], {4}]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.037

```
result2b = Map[Count[1], data2[[All, All, 2, 1]], {2}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.12

```
(result2 = Array[0 &, n3];
 Do[result2[[j]] = Table[Count[Flatten@(data2[[j, i, 2]]), u_ /; u == 1], 
  {i, 1, n1}];, {j, 1, n3}];) // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 7.8

```
result2 == result2a == result2b
```

> True

Comment: Great ... what do you think about `result2`. Now the Indices in the `result2` double loop are correct.

Comment: @lio, please see the update.

Comment: Since especially `n3` in my real problems is much larger than 50 I vote for your fast solution. Thank you for the timings. May I ask you something: how can the creation of `data2` also be expressed instead of using the do loop `Do[data2[[i]] = {#, {RandomInteger[3, 20]}} & /@ Range[n1];, {i, 1, n3}];`?

Comment: @li, thank you for the accept. You can do `data2b = Table[
  Transpose[{Range[n1], RandomInteger[3, {n1, 20}]}], {i, 1, n3}]`

Answer (score 5):

For your `result1`:

```
Count[1] /@ data1[[All, 2, 1]]
```

For your `result2`:

```
Map[Count[1], data2[[All, All, 2, 1]], {2}];
```

Comment: This is great ...

Comment: Do you have an idea for `result2` improvement?

Comment: @lio Yes, I've added something for result2 as well. You can check that they give the same output as your `result1` and `result2` respectively.